# show and hide <h1> dynamically in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 5.2.

I have the following inside my body on my view:

```
<div class="headerDetails">

    <h1> Nombre Empresa: #{loginController.login.empresa} </h1>

    <h1> Bienvenido: #{loginController.login.nombre}</h1>

</div>
```

I want to dynamically hide and show the first `<h1>` depending on what user logged in. What is the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You could enclose `<h1>` (and `<h2>`, if needed) inside a standard JSF component like `<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{booleanCondition}">` (or `<ui:fragment rendered="#{booleanCondition}">`) specifying the desired condition in the `rendered` attribute. This will conditionally render an HTML `<div>` element (without `layout="block"`, it will render an HTML `<span>` element, if one of the attributes like `id`, `style`, `styleClass`  is specified).

Comment: Excellent! It worked! I should have known how to do that

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for those who are interested:

```
<div class="headerDetails">

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{loginTipoController.isEmpresarial()}">

        <h1> Nombre Empresa: #{loginController.login.empresa} </h1>

    </h:panelGroup>

    <h1> Bienvenido: #{loginController.login.nombre}</h1>

</div>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoginTipoController {

    private LoginTipo tipo;

    public LoginTipo getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(LoginTipo tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {   
        tipo = new LoginTipo();

        //setting the value from get request
        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        tipo.setTipo(params.get("tipo"));
    }

    public boolean isEmpresarial()
    {
        if(tipo.getTipo().equals("emp")) return true;

        else return false;
    }

}
```

If the user is "ind", I don't want to show the `<h1>` tag. If it is "emp", I want to show the tag.